# Parse Server: manually convert anonymous user to 'real' user?

Tags: parse-server

I have anonymous users on my Parse Server. For some special cases, I would like to manually (from the Dashboard) convert them to 'real' users. I have tested this by manually setting a new username and password to the user, and it seems to work. However, the *authData* is still set and I can't delete it. Also, don’t know if there could be other side effects.

Anyone knows more about this?

Comment: Changing the password of a user de-authenticates all their current sessions.  If you manually create this user, they'll need to sign in with their new credentials to continue using the app.

Comment: That's not a problem in this case. I'm wondering if this manual conversion from anonymous to 'real' user could have any strange effects.

Comment: Just discovered that my iOS app still detects the user as anonymous. (PFAnonymousUtils isLinkedWithUser...). I suspect that is because the anonymous authData is still there.

Comment: Anonymous auth should effectively be stripped when the signup with username / password is complete and succeeded. Did you use a save or a signup?

Comment: I have this working with signup in my iOS app, but this questions was related to special cases where I'd like to convert a user manually from the Dashboard (if possible). When just setting username and password manually the iOS app still treats the user as anonymous. Also tried using Cloud Code and user.signup. Works better. The iOS app recognizes the user as a 'real' user. However, authData is still filled. Any thoughts?

Comment: this should be fine.  you can delete the auth data by clicking on it and hitting delete.